# Connection timeout in virtuoso, even after changing the MaxQueryExecutionTime

Tags: virtuoso

I changed the Virtuoso 6.1 configuration in order to avoid the Timeout constraint.

Here is the important part of the `virtuoso.ini`:

```
MaxQueryCostEstimationTime  = 40000 ; in seconds
MaxQueryExecutionTime       = 60000 ; in seconds
```

However, it still times out for complex queries.

Did I miss something?

Comment: It is certainly still possible for complex queries to exceed your new setting.  Also note that the query may be submitted with a lower timeout -- which takes effect if it's lower than the server-side setting.  We need more information about how you're submitting these complex queries (`curl`? `/sparql` web form? another method) and what error message (if any) you're getting. (Addressing this with Virtuoso 6 is possible, but Virtuoso 7 remains strongly recommended, and will improve performance immensely...)

Comment: I am wondering whether you are actually hitting "connection timeout" as in your question title, or "query timeout" as suggested by your question body...  If connection timeouts are the issue, the query timeout adjustments (`MaxQueryCostEstimationTime`, `MaxQueryExecutionTime`) will certainly not help.